# What is the use of a form as opposed to pulling the info in a textbox when a submit button is pressed?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to design an application that takes several settings into consideration when processing (scale, height, base-height, etc.). I'm learning HTML, and from looking into it, I can take in user text input through a form. However, I think that I can pull the text from a [textarea](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp). What are the benefits of using the form as opposed to manually processing with a textarea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the html form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066693/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-form-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the `<form></form>` tag encapsulates the inputs needed for submitting specific information via a specific method/action without needing to define the collection if inputs/selects/textareas with Javascript.

With this ability, you can have a search feature, billing form and zip code locator - for examples - on the same page. The "submit" for that form must be inside the form tags.