# Use of html form with JS frameworks offering reactivity and view models

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

What is the use of the html form element in today's world of modern web app development with reactive and view model based JS frameworks? The data submission from the client to the server happens via data in the view models through REST or its derivative techniques. And this according to me has made form obsolete. Infact I would say using form will bring in more complexities like auto submission of entire form on pressing enter, needing you to explicitly suppress the default behavior.

Even in terms usage of semantic elements for accessibility, I don't see any benefits. 
The input, select and button elements provide good info to the accessible users to understand what the application is trying to do.

So is there any reason to use form element in modern webapp development?

Answer (score 0):

Submission on enter key, submit event along of other 
peculiarities of `<form />` are features, not bugs.

A lot of modern libraries (Eg: [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/packages/formik/src/Form.tsx)) relies on `<form />` tag. That's because it both has nice features and it's *semantic*

Comment: They're ofcourse features. And well intended ones for good old days. But the behavior of page refreshing is quite annoying (without event.preventDefault call). Semantic is one thing as I already mentioned in the question. Could you elaborate the `nice` part?

Comment: Take a look at this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066693/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-form-tag/31066963