# Correct HTML Semantic for editable items on lists

Tags: html

I'm currently facing a situation that I have never faced before. I need to create a list of users, each item of the list is editable and automatically sends data to our backend.

The basic example that I can give is the following:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <label for="username">User name</label>
  <input id="username"/>
  <label for="enabled">Enabled</label>
  <input id="enabled" type="checkbox" />
 </li>
</ul>
```

This is just a simple example, but it is basically the structure, as you can see I have not added any form and that is the question that I have.

Based on my knowledge of semantic HTML or each item is a form:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <form>
   <label for="username">User name</label>
   <input id="username"/>
   <label for="enabled">Enabled</label>
   <input id="enabled" type="checkbox" />
  </form>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Or I would do a single form for the entire list:

```
<form>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <label for="username">User name</label>
   <input id="username"/>
   <label for="enabled">Enabled</label>
   <input id="enabled" type="checkbox" />
  </li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

But, my first attempt before coming here to ask, I tried to look on some websites, like youtube, twitch, gmail and even here, on stackoverflow to see how they do it, and I found this on Twitch that made me think if a form is even necessary. If you click on your avatar on twitch, it give you two options:

[image: Online and share activity sliders on twitch]

Inspecting the page I could only find a label and an input for each of those options, but looking at the remaining HTML I could **not** find any form nor a div with form role.

So I'm thinking, is semantically correct to have input outside of any forms? If so, what are the conditions to have a form or not?

Because as far I could understand, whenever you need to submit data somewhere, you should have a form for semantically reasons.

Comment: The main purpose of the `<form>` element is to tie everything together in the event of a *submit* happening (be it by clicking a button, or an enter-keypress in a textfield or triggered by script or whatever - the form itself defines the target url and defines a scope for all the input/textarea/etc elements inside it (the scope within which their `name` attr should be unique for ex).

Comment: If you're not making use of traditional form submissions (for example because you're using ajax requests) then you can effectively just wrap a dummy `<form>` element around the whole thing (html4/xhtml) or leave it out altogether (html5). -- In other words, the <form> element is *semantically* speaking entirely optional (though somewhat recommended if the layout allows for it). It is *functionally* required in cases where you're relying on traditional html form submission without the use of scripts (or situations where you use traditional form submission as noscript fallback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although is a best practice, sometimes yout your `input` tag doesn't need to be inside a form or a div with form role. On this case you can simply create the elements and handle the inputs through JS. I don't think there's actually a clear rule for whether using `form` or not. It was most commonly used before along with the `type="submit"` to pass data easily on the URL, but with AJAX and web frameworks there's no more need for that and the `action` attribute might actually trick you.

Check out these references:

- [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)
- [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31066963/6110143)

One other reason you might not find a `form` or equivalent role on your HTML inspection is because most (if not all) of these platforms run on top of various javascript frameworks, like React, Angular, etc. and the role is injected through js.